# Работа с внешним массивом внутри функции переданным как параметр Delphi 10.2

Tags: массивы, delphi

Насколько знаю при передачи массива в процедуру/функцию, передаётся её адрес, но не сам массив.

```
type
  TBigData = array of UInt64;

procedure Add_pr(Var arr_to: TBigData; Const arr_from: TBigData); --суммирует два массива, результат пишет в первый
begin
   arr_to[i] := arr_to[i] + arr_from[i];//Код пропущен, просто суммирование двух массивов в первый
end;

function Add_fu(Const arr_to, arr_from: TBigData): TBigData; --суммирует два массива, результат пишет в третий (fun.Result)
begin
   Result[i] := arr_to[i] + arr_from[i];//Код пропущен, просто суммирование двух массивов в третий
end;
```

Иногда нужно суммировать в один из двух массивов, которые слагаемые, иногда нужно вообще новый создать(третий) и туда занести сумму.

Важна скорость работы алгоритма, вопрос по коду, хочется не следить за двумя версиями процедуры-функции(есть такие же "пары" по делению, умножению, отниманию и т.д. всё для того же, работы внутри двух массивов, или результат внести в третий).

Как объединить код проц/функ не потеряв скорости алгоритма?
Что-то вроде

```
function Add_fu(Var arr_to: TBigData; Const arr_from: TBigData): TBigData;
begin
   Result[i] := arr_to[i] + arr_from[i];
end;
```

При вызове если нужно работать создать третий массив:

```
arr3 := Add_fu(arr1,arr2);
```

Если нужно занести сумму в первый массив слагаемое, третий массив-результат не нужен:

```
arr1 := Add_fu(arr1,arr2);
```

Можно ли обойтись малой кровью не потеряв скорости работы алгоритма, с минимум изменений.
Не будет ли при таком вызове (`arr1 := Add_fu(arr1,arr2)`) проблем и создания копий и прочих тормозов и ошибок?
Вроде бы внутри функции `Result`, `arr_to` это просто ссылка на адрес, и в зависимости от вызова функции они могут быть одним тем же или разным массивами, но кто знает, как это реализовано в Delphi 10.2?

Comment: Что имеется в виду под `Delphi .Net`??

Comment: Delphi 10.2 он же вроде на .Net 3.5 по крайней мере скачивать приходится, когда устанавливаешь

Comment: @AntVa Это нужно инсталятору, а не Delphi.

Comment: дотнет нужен инсталлятору и среде разработки (лучше бы избавились от этого), а приложения нативные, поэтому не нужно связывать .net с Delphi.

Comment: Какая жуть, полгига скачать, ради установщика? Есть же легкие инстал-шиелды, у меня были проблемы с Виндоус-Обновлялкой, не мог поставить из-за это дельфи, .Net не устанавливался из-за Винды.

Comment: "и среде разработки (лучше бы избавились от этого)" мне как-то избавится? Или компании? Я б с удовольствием, поменьше exe-ник, и максимум оптимальный код компилятора :)

Comment: Никак не избавиться. К компилятору и коду это отношения не имеет.

Comment: Вопрос разрешился?

Comment: Тогда стоит выбрать ответ (по выбранной семантике больше подходит ответ Igor)и пометить его как принятый (галочкой). За второй можно плюсик поставить ;)

Comment: Ответ MBo как раз таки больше подошел, он шире.

Comment: "Это действие требует 15 баллов репутации" плюсы не ставятся.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Можно так cделать и использовать по-разному

```
procedure Add(A, B, C: TBigData);
begin
  ... C[i] := A[i] + B[i];
end; 

Add(X, Y, Z);   //сумму в третий
Add(X, Y, X);   //сумму в первый
Add(X, X, X);   //первый удвоить
```

Comment: Зачем здесь нужен `var`?

Comment: Чтобы работать не с копиями

Comment: переменные динамических массивов - указатели

Comment: Мда, заглянув, уже забыл, о чём речь и какой там тип был.

Answer (score 2):

```
function Add(arr_to: TBigData; arr_from: TBigData; aCreateResult: boolean): TBigData;
begin
  if aCreateResult then
    SetLength(result, Length(arr_to));
  else
    result := arr_to;

  ...
    result[i] := arr_to[i] + arr_from[i];
end;
```

Я сделаю вид, что не заметил "Delphi.NET".  Если не ошибаюсь, последняя версия Delphi с дотнетовской вариацией была Delphi 2006.

Comment: Почему нельзя установить Delphi 10.2 без .Net ?